# Postgres regexp_replace query usage

Tags: regex, postgresql

We have a column with a particular prefix value followed by dynamic digits, for example,

```
AAAA0000
AAAA0001
AAAA0002
AAAA0003
... 
...
```

Now we want to update the prefix value from `AAAA` to `BBBB` in all the rows it exists. I have tried using `regexp_replace`, `replace` and also other possible function but without success.

Could you please help me to do this?

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? And what was the problem? Or the error?

Comment: I have tried the following options,                                                              update tablename set column_name = regexp_replace ('string_value', '.....','update_value' ) where ep2_entity_id = 'string_value',                                   but, String value can't be constant otherwise i can't update other records

Answer (score 1):

update table_name set the_column = 'BBBB'||substr(the_column, 6,13) where the_column like 'AAAA%';

Where as, 6 is the starting position of the digits and 13 is the ending position of the string.. 
So the value 'BBBB' will get updated till the position 5 and then the concatenation of sub string as extracted above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for regex here:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = 'BBBB'||substr(the_column, 5)
where the_column like 'AAAA%';
```

Comment: Hi, Let me try this option and update here. I haven't tried this option.

Comment: I have tried the below query with a little bit improvisation and it did work for me,                                                                                                                     update table_name set the_column = 'BBBB'||substr(ep2_entity_id, 6,13)
where the_column like 'AAAA%'; t

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you use `regexp_replace` here:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = regexp_replace(the_column, '^AAAA', 'BBBB');
```

Comment: Hi, You mean columns name in the first parameter, also i need to update the prefix of string, so the regexp pattern will not help.. i think

Comment: By this way, only tostring is getting overwritten, all other values are vanished. :(